# $\mathbf\Sigma^1_n$ formulae, $\mathbf\Sigma^1_n$ subsets of $\mathbb R$, and eventually also $\Sigma_n$ formulae?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Good morning,

I always have found some difficulties in understanding the connection between the analytic hierarchy, the projective hierarchy and the Lévy hierarchy.

First of all, I write my definitions so I can check if I understood correctly what I'm really telling. A formula is $\Sigma^1_0$ if it is some first-order sentence in the language of arithmetic (so, ad example, $\exists x\in\omega: x+1=y$ could be $\Sigma^1_0$ I guess). A formula is $\Pi^1_n$ if its complementary is $\Sigma^1_n$, and a formula is $\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ if it is of the form $(\exists x\in\mathbb R)\ \psi(x)$ where $\psi(x)$ is a $\Pi^1_n$ formula. Here the $\mathbb R$ means anything you want, $\omega^\omega$, or $\wp(\omega)$, it's not really important. Now, a sentence is $\mathbf\Sigma^1_n$ if it is a $\Sigma^1_n$ formula in which all free variables have been replaced with parameters belonging to $\mathbb R$.

At the same time, I can define analytic subsets of $\mathbb R$ by telling: $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ is analytic if and only if it's the continuous image (or projection) of a Borel set. We call $\mathbf\Sigma^1_1$ the analytic sets. Then a set is $\mathbf\Pi^1_n$ if it's the complementary of a $\mathbf\Sigma^1_n$ set, and it is a $\mathbf\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ set if it is the continuous image (or projection) of a $\mathbf\Pi^1_n$ set. And this is fine.

The third hierarchy I guess it's the Lévy one, that is: a formula in the language of set theory is $\Delta_0$ (or $\Sigma_0$, or $\Pi_0$) if all its quantifiers are bounded. A formula is $\Sigma_{n+1}$ if it's of the form $\exists x\ \psi(x)$ where $\psi(x)$ is a $\Pi_n$ formula, and $\Pi_{n+1}$ if it's of the form $\forall x\ \psi(x)$ where $\psi(x)$ is a $\Sigma_n$ formula. Then usually you consider these notions up to logical equivalence, so every $\Sigma_n$ formula is the complementary of a $\Pi_n$ formula and so on.

My question is the following one: assuming these definitions are correct, which are the connections between them? For example, which of the following facts are true?

(1) A subset $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ is $\mathbf\Sigma^1_{n}$ if and only if there is a $\mathbf\Sigma^1_n$ formula $\varphi(x,y)$ and a real parameter $a\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$A=\{x\in\mathbb R: \varphi(x,a)\}.$$

(2) A subset $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ is $\mathbf\Sigma^1_{n}$ if and only if there is a $\Sigma_n$ formula $\psi(x)$ such that
$$A=\{x\in\mathbb R: \psi(x)\}.$$

(3) Some kind of connections between $\Sigma_n$ formulae (maybe with parameters in $H_{\omega_1}$?) and $\mathbf\Sigma^1_n$ formulae? Maybe $\mathbf\Sigma^1_{n+1}$ even...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer (I'll complete this later when I have time):

The Levy hierarchy (the $\Sigma_n$s) quickly outstrips the other two hierarchies, which are indeed connected roughly as you suspect (although there are some subtleties with small $n$). The key point is that we can define $\mathbb{R}$ in the language of set theory. This means that for large enough $n$ - say, $n>3$ - **every** projective (= topologically ${\bf \Sigma}^1_k$ for some $k$) set of reals is $\Sigma_n$ definable in $V$.

That said, the Levy hierarchy can *relativize* to any transitive set of interest. Here things can go back to being nice: we can think of $\mathsf{HC}$ (= the hereditarily countable sets) as being yet another "flavor" of the reals, and - letting $b:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathsf{HC}$ be a "reasonable" bijection - for sufficiently large $n$ we do get that $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is topologically ${\bf\Sigma}^1_n$ iff $b[X]=\{b(x):x\in X\}$ is $\Sigma_n$-in-$\mathsf{HC}$.

But in general you should always be wary of the Levy hierarchy - it's *incredibly* powerful!

Comment: Thank you Noah. Yeah, right, the Lévy hierarchy does indeed feel way stronger than the others (also mainly because every formula in the language of set theory is in the Lévy hierarchy, but not every formula in the language of set theory is in the projective hierarchy of formulae). How much large should be the $n$ for the two relations you mentioned to work? I'm guessing the problems are mainly with $n\le 2$, right?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but if you could help me a bit more understand the subject I would be very grateful. If you don't have time to write a longer answer, don't worry, but could you please suggest to me some reference where to study these hierarchies? In particular the projective formulae